# Is there a way to prevent Postgres triggers from triggering before Java/EclipseLink transaction commits

Tags: postgresql, triggers, java, orm

I have a Java application that connects to a **Postgres DB** using EclipseLink.

My problem is that database triggers are triggered before the *Java/EclipseLink* transaction is completed causing the data to be incorrect.

**Example**:

> There is a trigger to update a `order_logs` table every time there is an `insert` or `update` on the `orders` table.

**Problem**:

> When a `setter()` method is called on an `OrderEntity` instance, the database logs indicate that the trigger is run for every two `setter()` method calls within the same transaction. This results in the `order_logs` table having multiple rows for only one update.

My question is that is there a way to force/ensure that the trigger is triggered only at the end of a transaction. I had a look at [this page](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html) but deferring looks like it's just for foreign keys. My methods are wrapped with the `@Transactional` annotation.

The trigger was created using:

```
create trigger my_insert_update_trigger after
  insert or update
      on
        public.my_table for each row execute procedure my_insert_update_trigger_function();
```

Comment: If you run an insert and an update for the same row, the trigger is going to be called twice. No way around that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up having to add this line:

`<property name="eclipselink.persistence-context.flush-mode" value="COMMIT" />`

to the `persistence.xml` file as documented in [persistence-context.flush-mode](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/toplink/TLJPA/p_persistence_context_flushmode.htm#TLJPA1005) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40956753/2155645).